# Can I add a WebTab using the REST API?

Tags: rest-api, web-tab

I want to create an app that integrates with the REST API using OAuth and for the front-end to be available for users as a tab inside Salesforce.  I found how to create a WebTab manually and while the end result is exactly what I want, it required a multistep process that I would like to automate.

Essentially I want to be able to have users perform the OAuth and then have a tab appear in their Salesforce installation that points at my app.  Is this possible? if not what is the easiest way to add a simple tab that just contains an external webapp? Will I have to use the App Exchange thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the tab plus all the required settings using a Managed Package. In fact, this would be the ideal scenario, since it would allow them to control which user(s) have access to the tab, etc. Administrators will have to use an installation link, but listing on the AppExchange is optional. It will still be "uploaded" to the AppExchange, but the security review is yet optional if you want to provide your own installation mechanism (e.g. they click on a link from your website, login, and install). While you could also create a tab using the REST Metadata API, this would require significant effort compared to simply giving them a link to click on and install.

Comment: can this managed package just be a webtab? or does it need to be something like a visualforce app?

Comment: You can use just the tab, and it can be a normal webtab, although you'll probably want to add an app as well, so users can switch to it without administrators having to add it to the other apps.